# Which Xcode template should I use?

Tags: xcode, ios5, uistoryboard, xcode-template

I want to make an application which shows you the schedule for your school.

It should mainly display the current day and allow you to scroll left and right for switching to the day before or the day after the current selected day.

There should also be a settings view.

I'm new to making iOS apps, so which Xcode template should I use?
I think Page-Based Application seems to fit the most, however is this right?
I don't want the page curl transition, just a normal scrolling transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically start with a Tabbed Application or Master Detail view, but normally just a Tabbed Application and put in a tableview wrapped in a navigation controller.  The tabs allow me to structure out different sections of the app and using table views gives you the nice slide in of new views.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I don't think I need tabs actually.

Comment: Start with master detail view then.  Its a pretty simple template to get your handle on what you're doing.